# Plotting a 3D Filled Radius Against a Helical Surface and Cylinder

Tags: graphics3d

Is there a way to plot a `Tube` with its cross section going from 180 degrees to 270 degrees?

I would like it to look something like the cross section of this cylinder segment:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{0.25 Cos[θ]+ 0.5, 0.25 Sin[θ]+0.5, z},
 {θ, 180Degree, 270Degree}, {z, 0, 2}, 
 Mesh -> None, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, ViewPoint -> Top]
```

I would like to replace `helixWeld` in the following code with a 180 degree to 270 degree filled radius segment:

```
surf = ParametricPlot3D[{v Cos[u],v Sin[u], u 0.25 Pi}, {u, 0, 4 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.12], PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> Full, 
 Mesh -> None, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 ViewPoint -> {1, 2, 1}, ImageSize -> 500];

helixWeld = ParametricPlot3D[{1.13 Cos[t], 1.13 Sin[t], t 0.25 Pi}, {t, 0, 4 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle->{Tube[0.2],Black}];

shaft = Graphics3D[{LightGray,{CapForm["Butt"],Tube[{{0, 0, -0.4}, {0, 0, 10.4}}, 1]}}];

Show[{surf, helixWeld, shaft}, PlotRange -> All, Background -> LightYellow]
```

I'm attempting to exchange the filled weld with a filled radius.

Comment: BTW, I'm using Mma 8.0.4 on Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: "180 degrees to 270 degrees" is a bit vague. Relative to what position is this angle?